# Scope of a variable in python

Tags: python

In python, local variable can be accessed only inside a block. According to python block will start with :[colon] and all the statements inside the block will have same indentation. But in **for** loop and in **if** statement am using a local variable and its able to access outside the block. Can anyone explain how its possible. Code is as follows:

```
def a():
    for i in range(0,4):
        i=i+1
    print(i)
    if(True):
        ii=10
        print("Inside",ii)
    print("Outside",ii)
a()

Output:
4
Inside 10
Outside 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion that "local variable can be accessed only inside a block" is just not true in Python, as your code demonstrates.

The only things that introduce scope in Python are modules, classes, and functions.

Comment: Ya i understood that, but still For and if also considered as block right?

Comment: @Mathan yes, they are blocks, *but not scopes*. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/3001761.